# Can I see a log for a stuck software update?

Tags: macos, software-update

My Mac is running a software update (update to macOS 10.13.2) but the process seems to be stuck: for the past hour, it’s been displaying the gray Apple logo screen with the progress bar indicating around 90%.

Is there some way to get a log or some more information about what the update is doing? Preferably without stopping it completely in case I am wrong about it being stuck?

Comment: After another hour, I decided to give up and just forced a reboot. As far as I can tell from “system.log” in Console, the update was successfully applied, but the reboot after the update got stuck for some unclear reason (there are a lot of messages related to “com.apple.mdworker.shared” saying [the] “Service exited due to signal: Bus error:”). The “About this Mac” window shows it's running 10.13.2. It would still be good to have an answer to my question on whether it is possible to see the log without interrupting an update or reboot though, in case I have another stuck update in the future.

Comment: I would start with `$ sudo show log | grep updated` but I've never tried.